# report before and after combinations in dimension table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

We have a star schema with a fact table and a few dimensions.  The fact table tracks quarterly premium by account.  There is a dimension table that stores the account information like accountnum, AccountName, and Broker.

There can be multiple brokers per account.  For example, Account 123 can have Broker A and Broker B.  The dimension is setup as a type 2 SCD, so if anything changes with the account, it creates a new row with the respective Begin and End Dates.

What i've been asked to do is come up with a design so taht we can report changes in the Account Brokers from Quarter to Quarter and show what the prior Broker was and what the new Broker is.  So if Account 123 had Broker A in Q1 and now has Broker B in Q2, it would show that in Q2 Broker A went to Broker B and Broker B came from Broker A.  So i need to be able to show where it came from and where it went to.

I wasn't sure how to implement this in a dimensional model or maybe create a one-off flat table to store the changes to make it easy to report by quarter.

thanks
Scott